# XAMPP Apache Server shutdowns automatically

Tags: apache, xampp, shutdown

Can't start Apache Server. But Mysql server is working. Apache Sever shutdowns automatically!!

```
1:34:52 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
1:34:52 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
1:34:52 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
1:34:52 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
1:34:52 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
1:34:52 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
1:34:52 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time Skype is the reason for this.

If you have Skype go to Skype then go to Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection and uncheck the Use port 80 and 443 for incoming connections. After that jsut restart Apache and this should do the trick.

If you don't have Skype installed then make sure to check in what port is your Apache, if it's on 80 change it to 8080